# Spawning of nested background/parallel processes fails

Tags: r, parallel-processing, future, amazon-ecs, callr

I'm trying to build a dockerized R microservice that runs on [AWS ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) and involves packages [{future}](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future), [{future.callr}](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future.callr) and [{furrr}](https://github.com/DavisVaughan/furrr) (and thus implicitly [{callr}](https://github.com/r-lib/callr) and [{processx}](https://github.com/r-lib/processx))

When I do local testing with a docker container that is limited to **1 CPU** and **650 MB** memory (matches the stage setup of a client of mine; production has **1500 MB** and *4 CPUs*), everything works fine.

However, on the actual AWS instance I get the following errors:

**Error 1:**

```
Error in get_result(out, private$options) : 
  callr subprocess failed: could not start R, exited with non-zero status, has crashed or was killed
```

**Error 2:**

```
Error in rethrow_call(c_processx_exec, command, c(command, args), stdin,  : 
  Cannot fork when running '/usr/local/lib/R/bin/R' (system error -12, Unknown error -12) @unix/processx.c:499 (processx_exec)
```

I'm completely out of my depth here, would anyone be able to give me a hint to what's going on and/or how I can fix this?

It's kind of hard to provide a reprex on this issue, but here's the main gist of the general setup:

### Ensuring background processes

```
ensure_background_processes <- function(workers_level_1, workers_level_2){
  future::plan(
    list(
      future::tweak(future.callr::callr, workers = workers_level_1),
      future::tweak(future.callr::callr, workers = workers_level_2)
    )
  )
}
```

### Wrapper function that handles two operations to happen "concurrently" where each operation needs to be parallelized over 3 entities (so `x` would e.g. be of length 3)

```
foo <- function(x) {
  future::future({
    x %>%
      furrr::future_map(
        ~.x %>% bar()
      )
  })

  future::future({
    x %>%
      furrr::future_map(
        ~.x %>% baz()
      )
  })
}
```

### Actual functions to be executed in each parallelization cycle

```
bar <- function(x) {
  # Do something useful in a while loop
}

baz <- function(x) {
  # Do something useful in a while loop
}
```

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I have the same error with parallelizing with multidplyr on docker containers.

My error was this: `Cannot fork when running '/usr/local/lib/R/bin/R' (system error -12, Unknown error -12) @unix/processx.c:499 (processx_exec)>`

Comment: No, unfortunately not :-/